# Rigid body objects interact with armature bone?

Tags: armature, bones, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

Is it possible in Blender to create an object (human + armature), rig it and make it to interact with other rigid body objects?
[image]

Will this possible in the next blender updates?

Comment: It's possible now.  You make non-rendering rigid bodies with the "animated" trait and parent them to your bones.